# Is it possible to modify the output column delimiter in MySQL query results?

Tags: command-line, mysql, console

Is it possible to modify the string used to delimit output columns in command line MySQL query results? E.g. could I change `|` to `!` or `||`?

Answer (score 2):

According to the manual (on linux `man mysql`) starting mysql with `-s -r` options will change your queries from

```
% mysql
mysql> SELECT CHAR(92);
+----------+
| CHAR(92) |
+----------+
| \        |
+----------+
```

to

```
% mysql -s -r
mysql> SELECT CHAR(92);
CHAR(92)
\
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes. From mysql documentation:

> [mysql commandline] When used interactively, query results are presented in an ASCII-table format. When used noninteractively (for example, as a filter), the result is presented in tab-separated format. The output format can be changed using command options.

Thus, you can pipe mysql commandlines output to sed and change tabs to whatever you want.

see sed doc: http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html#uh-6

also there seems to be a patch to add that option explicitly: http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=8904

Comment: Those are both good suggestions, but sadly they don't fit my needs. the first one because I want to work in interactive mode. And the second because I can not currently put the time into this. I was more looking for a built in solution but it seems that currently there is non. so I will continue reading my Hebrew from left to right :)